# Generate Geometric Random Graphs and check the connectivity

Tags: java, random, graph, probability, connectivity

I want to re-generate the graph below which consists of several nodes (say 1000) that's connected
the program will do the random graph then check if its connected or not
then I want to generate a connectivity graph for all the graphs done before and were connected with respect to the value r
like in the picture below

[image: different values of r]

I would like to use java programming language or python whatever easies, but I dont know how to start and what to do

Comment: You might want to reread [ask] and give more focus to your question. In it's current state I would say you should start with a concept of how the graph woud be generated (what exactly are the random portions), how you would want to represent it and how connectivity would be determined (Is it the same value for a certain number of nodes? Do graphs need to converge? Are they connected if they cross each other?) . The language you're doing it in would be the last thing to decide on, just pick what you're most familiar with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing the random geometric graph pseudocode [on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_geometric_graph) in Java?. It appears that authors of your figure have built several random (say, n=100; the source should have more details) graphs of `x` nodes in a unit square connected to all other nodes at distance `r` or less, for different values of `x` and `r`, and then plotted a line for each `r`. The most straightforward way to calculate `P[this is connected]` is to approximate it by `count_of_connected_with_these_parameters / count_of_disconnected_with_these_parameters`.

So my recommendation would be to:

1. write a `generateRandomGeometricGraphInUnitSquare(int nPoints, float r)` that returns a random geometric `Graph` with the given settings. I would use `JGraphT` to simplify implementation, since it already has a `Graph` class you can use.
2. build a loop that iterates through possible values of `x` and `r`, and for each combination of those values, performs `n` experiments to calculate the probability that a graph with those settings will be connected. If using `JGraphT`, you can know that just by calling [`isConnected`](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org.jgrapht.core/org/jgrapht/alg/connectivity/ConnectivityInspector.html#isConnected()) after passing your graph to a `ConnectivityInspector`. Output values that can be plotted using a spreadsheet or any other plotting mechanism of your choice.

In pseudocode, part 2 would look like:

```
 for (float r = 0.05f; r < 0.5f ; r += 0.1f) {
     for (int x = 5; x <= 100; x+= 5) {
         // perform experiment
         int connectedCount = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < nRepetitions; i++) {
             if (isGraphConnected(generateRandomGeometricGraphInUnitSquare(x, r)) {
                connectedCount ++;
             }
         }
         // generate output
         System.out.println("" + r + ", " + x + ", " + (connectedCount*1.0/nRepetitions));
     }
 }
```

If you need more details, ask new, more focused questions.